# Show admin-only submenu link to editors in WordPress. Results in error

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using a plugin which adds a submenu item to an admin menu like so:

`add_submenu_page( 'propertyhive', 'Property Hive Settings', 'Settings', 'manage_options', 'ph-settings', 'callback_fn' );`

Due to it stating `manage_options` it only appears for administrators. I need to show it for editors. Here's what I've tried in my theme's functions.php file:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'custom_settings_menu', 99 );
function custom_settings_menu()
{
    // Remove the submenu item first
    remove_submenu_page( 'propertyhive', 'ph-settings' );

    // Add it again but with different role (manage_propertyhive)
    // This role does exist as other submenu items ue it
    add_submenu_page( 'propertyhive', 'Property Hive Settings', 'Settings', 'manage_propertyhive', 'ph-settings', 'my_theme_callback_fn' );
}
```

Although this **does** show the submenu item correctly, I get the following error:

`Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page.`

Can anyone see anything obvious or have any inclinations as to what might cause this?

**Note:** The *manage_propertyhive* capability definitely **does** exist

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is happening because 'manage_propertyhive' is not a defined capability, therefore nobody will have access to that menu. You can either use one of the predefined wordpress capabilities which you can find [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Capability_vs._Role_Table) or you can define your own custom capability such as 'manage_propertyhive', by following the instructions [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/users/roles-and-capabilities/).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, but manage_propertyhive is definitely a capability. a) it's my plugin and b) other submenu items use it without issue. Thanks for your answer though

Answer (score 1):

1) Are you sure the `add_submenu_page()` function from the Plugin is copied correctly? `add_submenu_page()` accepts only 6 parameters - in your question it has 7 paramters with `propertyhive` being the capability and `manage_options` being the `menu_slug` (which is perplexing)

> https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_submenu_page/

2) I guess that administrators as well as editors got the capability `manage_propertyhive` ? If not make sure.

3) In your sample code the callback function for the new `propertyhive` submenu page is `my_theme_callback_fn` - did you insert the correct callback function here?

4) The fact that you add the submenu page to editors does not necessarily mean they can access that page - did you check the Plugin for further capability checks? Maybe in the code of the callback function or in some other function of the Plugin capabilities are checked again and editors are missing some capability.

Answer (score 1):

This must do the trick

```
function add_theme_caps() {
    $role = get_role( 'editor' );  
    $caps = (array)$role->capabilities;
    if(!array_key_exists('manage_propertyhive', $caps)) {
        $role->add_cap( 'manage_propertyhive' ); 
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'add_theme_caps');
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've set up the capability right, perhaps the parent page is not allowing access to submenu page, make sure user is able to access parent page...

This is the function that checks if user can access the page... If it returns false the error is displayed...
https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/4.6.1/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php#L1697-L1763

Besides checking several other things, it also checks if parent page is accessible by the user.

If that doesn't work, I'd suggest you to go to this file on you local install, and `var_dump` all vars that are checked before returning `false`, this is how we devs debug the errors... ;)

Make sure to restore the file to original file ( I just update the WordPress again, that restores all core files to their original state )...

Hope that helps.